# Is it possible to replace a character in a text file in constant time if the index of the character is known?

Tags: java, file, io, time-complexity

If I have a large text file is it possibe to replace the n-th character in constant or close to constant time? The best solution I'm aware of is using bufferedReader.skip to get to the index I want, then use readLine() to get each line, and appending them again (after changing the first line I read). For large files this can take a lot of time, so I'm curriouse if ther is any faster way of doing this

Comment: The `skip()` isn't really useful since you have to read the lines anyway. Your best solution is at least twice as bad as a simple solution of reading and writing lines directly until you get to your `n-th` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are random access files. Please see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for reference. You can use the `seek()` method to go to the n-th character and then one of the many different `write()` methods to manipulate the data. Please make sure you open the file in write-mode, otherwise you will get an exception.